# Get scripts site with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get the site scripts using `'Jsoup.connect(url).get().html()'`
but it doesn’t appear the script I want, does anyone know how I can get this script?

[Script I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9QKL.png)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear in the source because that video is inside an `iframe`. That iframe has its own `src` attribute (visible on your screenshot). Try getting that page instead.
EDIT:
Get the first page and parse it. Then select iframe src and when you have the second URL do the same again so get the page and parse it:

```
String iframeUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).get().selectFirst("#option-1 iframe").attr("src");
System.out.println(iframeUrl);
Document document = Jsoup.connect(iframeUrl).get();
System.out.println(document.html());
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the page?

Comment: It worked, but when he takes the iframe link and tries to connect from a 403 error, which from what I searched for is why I don't have access to enter this page, do you know any way to get access?

Comment: Try adding some headers to your request using `.header(name, value)`. It probably requires `User-Agent` header.